# How to enable verbs for static content in IIS7

Tags: iis-7

this question got me halfway there:

[How to tell IIS7 to allow POST to a text file (to solve 405)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/258399/how-to-tell-iis7-to-allow-post-to-a-text-file-to-solve-405)

except now my POST throws a 404 instead of a 405. If I load the page directly, it loads fine, but following a POST it 404s.

How can I enable GET and POST for static HTML files in IIS 7? I... have no idea what I'm doing. Please help!

Comment: For reference, I am deploying a static HTML mockup of a site that we are using for usability testing of the UI. One of the processes is a multi-step form wizard, so rather than rewrite the pages to not use POST even though I am not capturing/passing any data, I'd like to get the existing copy to just work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who stumble on this, http://sysadmin.circularvale.com/server-config/enabling-post-requests-to-static-eg-html-pages-using-iis-7/ details step by step resolution for this issue

Comment: Awesome, this is very close to what I ended up doing, but without having to rename the files. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  How could you get this to work with different file types in general, such as jpg?

Comment: I mean, it seems to have a little bit of trouble if data is saved as bytes and has non-textual characters.